# How to move wifi passwords from Ubuntu to Xubuntu?

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, password, gconf, keyrings

How can I move wifi passwords from Ubuntu to Xubuntu? Xubuntu doesnt have `.gconf/system/networking/connections`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/46397/how-to-move-wifi-passwords-to-a-new-installation

Comment: @loklaan This may be considered a duplicate of that question but Kangarooo probably posted here because the answers to that question seem to pretty much ignore the relevant differneces between Ubuntu and Xubuntu (specifically, that "Xubuntu doesnt have `.gconf/system/networking/connections`").

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve your problem, but passwords for the Network Manager (the default Xubuntu network application) are stored in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections.

However, I do not think you can simply copy-paste your Network files from Ubuntu to this directory. But feel free to give it a try!