# Synchronize wireless passwords between computers

Tags: wireless, sync, password

Is it possible to synchronize wireless network passwords between multiple computers running Ubuntu? It would save me a lot of time if I didn't need to re-enter every wireless password whenever I started using a new Ubuntu installation.

Comment: This topic has additional relevant details (explaining where the wireless passwords are saved, and how to move them to another computer): http://askubuntu.com/questions/46397/how-to-move-wifi-passwords-to-a-new-installation

Answer (score 0):

There may be some obscure way of doing this - there usually is with Linux!

However, what I do is to use LastPass with Firefox. It stores browser passwords but also has a secure note facility. Because it is the first thing I install, I effectively use it for sharing key settings including passwords.

Of course, this doesn't help if you have to install machines using only WiFi! In that case, I recommend simply putting the password in an obscure text file on a USB key while doing installs, then delete it. To add security, you could use a cross-platform security tool such as KeePass. Just make sure that you have the appropriate platform application on the key as well.

Comment: Is it possible to use LastPass to synchronize passwords for individual wireless networks?

Comment: There is a Windows tool for LastPass Premium customers that does this. Personally, I use the secure note facility which allows me to keep whatever information I like & share it with other LastPass users if needed. Just create one or more notes containing your WiFi passwords then you can easily copy and paste. If the computer doesn't have LastPass installed, you can simply log in to the web site to get the note.

Comment: Do you know where the wireless network passwords are usually saved in Ubuntu?

Comment: They can be accessed via the "System Settings" tool under "Network".