# Move wireless passwords to another computer

Tags: network-manager, keyrings, gnome-keyring

I am going to reinstall Ubuntu soon and want to move my wireless passwords I have to the new installation. What do I need to backup to put on the new installation?

Comment: They're all stored under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`, if you're using Network Manager that is (which is the default in Ubuntu). I've never tried this before though, so I'm not sure if simply copying and pasting those config files into another machine would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alaa mentioned, you'd want to copy your system connections to the new computer. Just doing a quick copy of files from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` will suffice.  If it doesn't work double check that permissions are rw for root only.

If you have any VPN connections, you'd want to do that for `/etc/NetworkManager/VPN` as well.

User-specific ones are stuck in your keyring. If you want, you can copy that to a remote location and drop it onto your new system.

Comment: Just copying the files was not enough on Ubuntu 16.04. The MAC address in the files also had to be changed. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/870661/8822) for detailed instructions.